# How to solve "no reference to" error in gfortran Linux?

Tags: linux, reference, fortran, gfortran

I run a code before with VS2012, visual Intel Fortran successfully but when I want to run this code with gfortan compiler in Linux I get this error :

```
no reference to ResidualModule_MOD_inviscidResidualConstructor
```

My code is :

```
module ResidualModule

use TransportModule
use CellsValuesCalculationModule
use MeanFlowModule
use FluxesModule
use precisionModule

    type , abstract :: AResidual                                                                        
    type(Convection) , pointer :: convectionObj                             
    type(MeanFlow) , pointer :: meanFlowObj
    type(MeshFacade) , pointer :: meshFacad
    type(Fluxes) , pointer , dimension(:) :: cellsResiduals
    real(dp) , pointer , dimension(: , :) :: facesValues , cellsValues
    contains
    procedure :: getCellsResiduals
    procedure(IcalculateCellsResiduals) , deferred :: calculateCellsResiduals
   end type    

   abstract interface
      subroutine IcalculateCellsResiduals(this)
          import :: AResidual
          class(AResidual) :: this
      end subroutine
   end interface

  type , extends(AResidual) :: InviscidResidual
  contains
      procedure :: calculateCellsResiduals => calInviscidCellsResiduals
   end type

   interface InviscidResidual
      procedure inviscidResidualConstructor
   end interface

    contains

  subroutine getCellsResiduals(this , cellsResiduals)
    class(AResidual) :: this
    type(Fluxes) , pointer , dimension(:) , intent(inout) :: cellsResiduals

     cellsResiduals => this%cellsResiduals
   end subroutine

   function inviscidResidualConstructor(convectionObj , meanFlowObj , 
    meshFacad)
        type(InviscidResidual) :: inviscidResidualConstructor
       type(Convection) , target :: convectionObj                             
       type(MeanFlow) , target :: meanFlowObj
       type(MeshFacade) , target :: meshFacad
       integer :: NC , NF

      inviscidResidualConstructor%convectionObj => convectionObj
      inviscidResidualConstructor%meanFlowObj => meanFlowObj
      inviscidResidualConstructor%meshFacad => meshFacad
      NC = meshFacad%getFvMeshNC()
      NF = meshFacad%getFvMeshNF()
      allocate(inviscidResidualConstructor%cellsResiduals(NC))
      allocate(inviscidResidualConstructor%cellsValues(5 , NC))
       allocate(inviscidResidualConstructor%facesValues(5 , NF))
    end function
   end module
```

!! some function of this module eliminated here for summarization.

In main program constructor of `InviscidResidual` is called:

```
residual = InviscidResidual(convectionObj , inviscidMeanFlow , meshFacad)
```

For summarization I avoid to write all of my code here.

Comment: While we appreciate that you've attempted to summarize, what we actually expect is a [mre], and you have not presented one.  There appears still to be considerably too much of the module code, and there is not enough of the main program.

Comment: I am sure this error because of this line of main function because when I inactive this line, program run successfully ! And its hard for me to create minimal reproducible example because this code  is  a bit complex for me

Comment: I do not dispute that the line presented from the main program is essential to reproducing the error, but context matters.  We ask for a [mre] so that the question is well defined, and therefore so that we can be confident that any answer we write actually addresses the question.  Moreover, the exercise of formulating an MRE is an excellent debugging technique in its own right, so you may even discover a solution for yourself that way.

Comment: You must also show how the program is linked. Make he MWE and show the *full* compiler output.